# Minus sign inside derivative operator, notation problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation

Hello fellow mathematicians. Can anybody help me understand what the minus (-) sign in this derivative means? Its the usual d/dy but with a minus added d-/dy. I can't find references, the book cited in the paragraph above doesn't explain either and I had never encountered it. I suspect it has to do with lateral diferentiation. I can't embed images since I usually read and never post.

I've found it on this article https://doi.org/10.1007/s11538-018-00558-w page 11, formula (15)

Comment: It seems to just be a typo because the $\kappa_{n}$ is actually normally differentiable since it is an integral with x as an endpoint.

Comment: It could have meant something like a Dini derivative (eg. left-limit), but it is mentioned nowhere  in the article.

Comment: You could try contacting the author to fix/explain it and prevent confusion for others.

Comment: @ThomasKojar thank you very much. I doubt it is a typo since it is written half a dozen times. I have no idea how to contact the author but I will try. Were you able to follow the proof ignoring it?

Comment: Yes. They probably just used some macro witn an error or copy-pasted the wrong command.